# How do i loop this to where i dont have to restart it to send a message

Tags: python, loops

```
from json import dumps

from httplib2 import Http

user_input = input() 
def main():
    """Hangouts Chat incoming webhook quickstart."""
    url = 'https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/1LcQvwAAAAE/messages?key=AIzaSyDdI0hCZtE6vySjMm-WEfRq3CPzqKqqsHI&token=JUUvDmAVkNOjOomaNGaTbqGqnAQBpNhRv3dMi5slCw%3D'
    bot_message = {
        'text' : user_input }

    message_headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}

    http_obj = Http()

    response = http_obj.request(
        uri=url,
        method='POST',
        headers=message_headers,
        body=dumps(bot_message),
    )

    print(response) 
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: whats the user_input is doing at the top? isn't it should be a parameter for the main function? like ```def main(user_input):``` ???

Comment: Welcome. Your question is very unclear. Please give us some proper examples so we have something to go on.

Comment: @GhostOps i dont know this is my first piece of code

Comment: @mTvare What are proper examples

Comment: @Dustin well try ```def main(user_input):``` at line 6 and ```main(user_input):``` at the end, and also try ```while user_input: main(user_input)```

Comment: @GhostOps Where do i put '''while user_input: main(user_input)'''

Comment: at the end, instead of ```main()``` cuz you said that you wanted to loop it right?

Comment: @GhostOps is there an way to make it ask for another input after sending?

Comment: i'll post about that in the answer section, check it out..

Comment: @GhostOps It was, can you explain how you did that so i can practice?

Comment: Hey @Dustin, i've edited the answer and added the explanation that you need, is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want, i guess

**Edit:** Explanation -

**First,** you have to define a variable of your input (thats what i've done before the `while user_input` line),

**Then,** you can see that i used `while user_input` which means the while loop will run while the input string is not an empty string (like '')

If you enter a non-empty string, the loop runs once, and asks for an another input, and the loop breaks if you enter an empty string, i think this is what you want i guess

```
from httplib2 import Http
import json

def main(user_input):
    """Hangouts Chat incoming webhook quickstart."""
    url = 'https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/1LcQvwAAAAE/messages?key=AIzaSyDdI0hCZtE6vySjMm-WEfRq3CPzqKqqsHI&token=JUUvDmAVkNOjOomaNGaTbqGqnAQBpNhRv3dMi5slCw%3D'
    bot_message = {
        'text' : user_input
    }

    message_headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}

    http_obj = Http()

    response = http_obj.request(
        uri=url,
        method='POST',
        headers=message_headers,
        body=json.dumps(bot_message),
    )

    print(response) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_input = input()
    while user_input:
        main(user_input)
        user_input = input()
```

Check if this works, and tell me if its not working...